# how to prevent resizing subview outof superview

Tags: ios

A UIImageView object is in UIView.

> UIImageView *foreview  = //
>
> UIView* backview = //

/* some preccess */

> [backview addSubView:foreview];

Thus foreview is backview's subview.

I am going to resize and rotate the backview so that don't out of foreview.

How to code?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `superview.clipsToBounds=YES` so that it will clip the subviews which goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

subviews will rotate with superview automatically.

if you don't  want foreview rotate with backView, you shouldn't add it as subview.